# ASP.NET Core : include jquery in a view

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, computer-science

I used `Bower` to download `jquery` in my ASP.NET Core project, and here's my project structure :

[image: projet tree structure]

Now, I want to include jquery in my view, and it's not working. I tried :

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

but in vain.

Comment: drag drop jquery from the solution link will auto generate

Comment: It's true that it autogenerates, but the browser returns a 500 error. Is it because the folder `bower_components` is private ?

Comment: so then create a public folder and set bower output dir in bower config fileon that folder

Answer (score 1):

Default location for the bower file is like

```
{
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

so you can reference them llike

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery.js"></script>
```

and also you can modify it, see the asp.net core documentation

[Documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/bower.html)

Comment: I did exactly as you said, but when I run Bower, the folder `bower_components` is always created outside wwwroot

Comment: under dependency it will always place that code for nodejs but the usable version will be under the output directory. You need to use that